# jQuery anytime picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, timepicker

I have a datepicker and time picker in my code as you can see below, but only the datepicker works. When I click the field with the timepicker it does not show a dropdown box?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/plugins/pickers/datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/assets/js/plugins/pickers/anytime.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
        $("#r1").click(function () {
            $(".text").show();
        });
        $("#r2").click(function () {
            $(".text").hide();
        });
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
            });
            $(function () {
                $(".timepicker").anytime({

                })

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there error in browser's console window ? where is jquery loaded can you please show complete code

Comment: I get an error in console saying 'Anytime' is not a function

Comment: try use:
AnyTime.picker(); 

instead of:
            $(function () {
                $(".timepicker").anytime({

                })

            });

Comment: @Lxwis can you please let me know where you are haivng jquery.js script tag

Comment: @Lxwis are you trying from this link . try to check is it working correctly after remove datepicker part means datepicker js script tag as well as whereever you used datepicker js function 

and if its not necessary for you to use datepicker.js then you can use 
http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Comment: @Lxwis I have written the working code in my answer please accept answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated code for working example of Anytime Picker

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.ama3.com/anytime/anytime.5.1.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  AnyTime.picker( "field1",
    { format: "%W, %M %D in the Year %z %E", firstDOW: 1 } );
  $("#field2").AnyTime_picker(
    { format: "%H:%i", labelTitle: "Hora",
      labelHour: "Hora", labelMinute: "Minuto" } );
  </script>
```

```css
<style>
/* anytime.5.1.2.min.css
Copyright 2008-2015 Andrew M. Andrews III.
License: creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
Any+Time is a trademark of Andrew M. Andrews III */

.AnyTime-pkr *{border:0;font:inherit;font-size:x-small;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.AnyTime-win{background-color:#F0F0F1;border:3px solid silver;display:inline-block;font:normal normal normal xx-small/normal sans-serif;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px}.AnyTime-pkr,.AnyTime-pkr *{text-align:center}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-cloak{background-color:#D7D7D7;opacity:.7;position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=70)}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-hdr{background-color:#D0D0D1;color:#606062;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:medium;font-weight:400;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px;border-radius:2px}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-x-btn{background-color:#FCFCFF;border:1px solid #F99;color:#FF9F9F;cursor:default;float:right;margin:.25em .25em 0 0;width:1.5em;-moz-border-radius:.4em;-webkit-border-radius:.4em;border-radius:.4em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-btn{background-color:#FCFCFE;border:1px solid #999;color:#606062;cursor:default;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;margin:0 .1em .1em 0;padding:.2em .3em;-moz-border-radius:.1em;-webkit-border-radius:.1em;border-radius:.1em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-body{margin:0 1em 1em 0}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-date{display:inline-block;margin-left:1em;vertical-align:top}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-lbl{color:#606063;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:100%;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;margin-top:.8em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yrs{width:20em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yrs-past-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yrs-ahead-btn{display:inline-block;width:2.4em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-prior-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-cur-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-next-btn{display:inline-block;width:4.8em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mons{width:20em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mons:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mon-btn{float:left;width:3.2em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mon7-btn{clear:left}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-dom-table{background-color:#F0F0F1;border:1px solid #E3E3E4;border-spacing:1px;width:20em}.AnyTime-pkr th.AnyTime-dow{background-color:#C0C0C1;color:#fff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:95%;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;padding:.1em .3em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-dom-btn{text-align:right;padding-right:.5em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-dom-btn-empty,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-min-ten-btn-empty,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-min-one-btn-empty,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-sec-ten-btn-empty,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-sec-one-btn-empty{background-color:#F3F3F4;border:1px solid #C0C0c1}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-time,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-hrs-am,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-hrs-pm,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mins-tens,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mins-ones,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-secs-tens,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-secs-ones{display:inline-block}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-hrs,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mins,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-secs,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-offs{display:inline-block;margin-left:1em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-hr-btn{text-align:right;width:3.5em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-min-ten-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-min-one-btn{width:2em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-sec-ten-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-sec-one-btn{width:2em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-off-cur-btn{display:inline-block;overflow:hidden}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-off-select-btn{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:2em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-selector{position:absolute}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-body-yr-selector{margin:.8em 1em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-mil,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-cent,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-dec,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-yr,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-era{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-mil-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-cent-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-dec-btn,.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-yr-btn{width:2em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-era-btn{margin-left:1em}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-off-selector{margin:1em 2em;position:absolute}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-body-off-selector{margin:.8em 1em;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;white-space:nowrap}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-off-off-btn{text-align:left}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-cur-btn{border:1px solid #333334;background-color:#C0C0C1;color:#FCFCFE;font-weight:700}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-out-btn{background-color:#F0F0F1;border:1px solid #C0C0c1}.AnyTime-pkr .AnyTime-focus-btn{border:1px dashed #000}
</style>
<style>
  #field2 { background-image:url("clock.png");
    background-position:right center; background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #FFC030;color:#3090C0;font-weight:bold}
  #AnyTime--field2 {background-color:#EFEFEF;border:1px solid #CCC}
  #AnyTime--field2 * {font-weight:bold}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-btn {background-color:#F9F9FC;
    border:1px solid #CCC;color:#3090C0}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-cur-btn {background-color:#FCF9F6;
      border:1px solid #FFC030;color:#FFC030}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-focus-btn {border-style:dotted}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-lbl {color:black}
  #AnyTime--field2 .AnyTime-hdr {background-color:#FFC030;color:white}
  </style>
```

```html
English: <input type="text" id="field1" size="50"
            value="Sunday, July 30th in the Year 1967 CE" /><br/>
Español: <input type="text" id="field2" value="12:34" />
```

Comment: @Lxwis Can you please check answer